# Sony Vegas 10 Video made from smaller quicktime mov videos look crap on youtube

Tags: editing, compression, vegas-pro

this has been a painful drama for days, trying to get a nice video on youtube for my girlfriend. It looks great on the mpg file sony vegas generates, but after uploading to youtube it look more than crap.

The original videos were shot with the Panasonic Lumix DMC-FS7 which uses quicktime mov format. The settings of these files are shown below, as seen in the detail tab of the properties of the video:

> General
>     Name: P1050576.MOV   Folder:
>   C:\Users\Public\Videos\maquiagem\3_abril   Type: QuickTime   Size:
>   322.52 MB (330,261,322 bytes)   Created: terça-feira, 3 de abril de 2012, 20:55:02   Modified: terça-feira, 3 de abril de 2012, 15:21:00
>   Accessed: terça-feira, 3 de abril de 2012, 20:55:02   Attributes:
>   Archive
>
> Streams   Video: 00:03:56.000, 30.000 fps, 848x480x24, Photo - JPEG
>   Audio: 00:03:56.000, 16,000 Hz, 16 Bit, Mono, 16-bit Big Endian
>
> ACID information   ACID chunk: no   Stretch chunk: no   Stretch list:
>   no   Stretch info2: no   Beat markers: no   Detected beats: no
>
> Other metadata   Regions/markers: no   Command markers: no
>
> Media manager   Media tags: no
>
> Plug-In   Name: qt7plug.dll   Folder: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Sony\Vegas Pro 10.0\FileIO Plug-Ins\qt7plug   Format: QuickTime
>   7   Version: Version 1.0 (Build 8261)   Company: Sony Creative
>   Software Inc.

I tried several settings, and in my last attempt I used the video tutorial below to borrow the settings:

www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXa849N9J9s

The resulting video looks great when playing locally (like all the ones before), but after uploading to youtube it has the same problems as the ones I had uploaded before:

I tried to convert the rendered video using the SUPER app, to see if it improves something. THe link in this (just checked and it really look bad, and at a much worse screen resolution.):
watch?v=OUBpdAjuNO8

I also tried to upload directly one of the many quicktime MOV files, to see if the problem is with the original format.

The resulting youtube video is below, there are many problems with the original MOV film after it got uploaded to youtube:

www.youtube.com/watch?v=54neVq4dAa0

I had installed the latest quicktime version. I read somewhere that sony vegas 10 requires an older version of quicktime, the 7.1.6 to work without problems.

I had doubted of this, but I just can't understand how a video run perfectly locally, and after uploaing it looks really bad :/

If nothing else works, I will try to downgrade my quicktime, but looking at the original file on youtube, now it looks the problem is some incompatibility with the mov. I would just had tought that after the video was rendered by sony vegas, this "supposed" incompatibility would be gone...

any help is welcome :) I uploaded the rendered video, if this helps in anyway to find the problem. You can confirm that it looks great locally?

thanks
Emerson

Comment: Looks like compression artifacts. Try rendering from Vegas to uncompressed AVI in native resolution i.e. 848x480 @ 24 fps. Then convert in SUPER to mp4  at a bitrate of about 2500 kbps; keep the native resolution and frame rate. Note that your source footage isn't HD, so it will look blurred if upscaled.

Comment: What happens if you "disable resample" in the clip properties before rendering. Any better?

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the original video if this can help to clear why the final youtube video doesn't work...
http://forum.antinovaordemmundial.com/arquivos/P1050576.MOV

Comment: I found this question whilst searching on Google for a solution to my problem. I worked a way to work around this problem [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/4279/636) which may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: I am looking for the solution to this too. I had the same problem two seconds in to my [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCtfeB7dEUQ&feature=plcp)

Answer (score 1):

I would try uploading the video to vimeo as well. Or, if you have your own website, uplaod it to there and create a simple page with an embedded player.

My experience is that YouTube sometimes adds a LOT of artifacts when it recompresses things. I've often experienced the problem you're having when I work with YouTube, but rarely with vimeo.

If Vimeo looks closer to your source material and self-hosting looks very close to it, I'd bet that it's YouTube's codec more than anything.

Good luck!

Comment: This should be an action of last resort. Youtube is by far the largest video hosting site on the net, and I've rarely seen problems of the sort shown in this case. This is most likely the result of some undesirable encoding parameters in the video sent to YT, most likely the scheme of I/B/P frames used.

Comment: Mulvya, where are these settings (I/B/P) done?

Comment: I tried to render after settings all video clips with the "reduce interlace flicker" and the disable resample, as suggested, but the result video was bad, and the sound is missing before the third minute:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw4raDwhPcM

http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/sony-vegas-10-video-made-from-smaller-quicktime-mov-videos-look-crap-on-youtube

I also just tried to get the good looking mp4 local file and converting it using formatfactory, but after uploading to youtube the result is still really bad:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuo-aa_A0UE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Could someone try to use the original file on sony vegas, and try to get upload it to youtube to see if the problem is the original file?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54neVq4dAa0